# Find $\int \frac{x^3}{x^2-1} \:\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus

> Find $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{x^3}{x^2-1} \:\mathrm{d}x$.

I think there are a few ways to do this. We could just break this up using long division or break it up into partial fractions then use long division. My homework says to break this up into its roots so that's why I brought up partial fractions. Is that the best way to do it here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I evaluate $\int{\frac{x^3}{x^2-1}dx}$ using trigonometric substitution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744417/how-do-i-evaluate-int-fracx3x2-1dx-using-trigonometric-substitution)

Answer (score 5):

No, you can evaluate it as follows:
$$
\int \frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}-1}dx=\int \frac{x^{3}-x+x}{x^{2}-1}dx\\
=\int xdx+\int \frac{x}{x^{2}-1}dx=\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln|x^{2}-1|+c
$$