# How do I evaluate $\int{\frac{x^3}{x^2-1}dx}$ using trigonometric substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

How do I use trigonometric substitution to rewrite and evaluate

$$\int{\dfrac{x^3}{x^2-1}dx}?$$

I have no trouble using long division of $x^3$ by $x^2-1$ which is $x+\dfrac{x}{x^2-1}$  to get the answer
$$\int \left(x+\dfrac{x}{x^2-1}\right)dx=\int x\ dx +\frac12\int \dfrac{2x}{x^2-1}dx$$$$=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac12\ln|x^2-1|+c$$

but I'm stuck on figuring out an appropriate *trigonometric substitution* to rewrite this integral.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I wouldn't use trig substitution. I might even just use $u$-substitution with $u = x^2 - 1$. But if constrained, I would let the $x^2 - 1$ guide me. This indicates that we want a triangle with hypotenuse $x$ and legs $1$ and $\sqrt{x^2 - 1}$. In this triangle, $\tan^2 \theta = x^2 - 1$.

Comment: Why would you do trigonometric substitution here?

Comment: I definitely agree that trigonometric substitution is a less-than-ideal method of solving this, but I'm supposed to learn how to evaluate this integral using multiple approaches, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess you can put $\;x=\sin u\implies dx=\cos u\,du\;$ , so

$$\int\frac{x^3}{x^2-1}dx=\int\frac{\sin^3u}{\sin^2u-1}\cos u\,du=-\int\frac{\sin^3u}{\cos u}du=-\int\frac{\sin u(1-\cos^2)}{\cos u}du=$$

$$=-\int\frac{\sin u}{\cos u}du+\int \sin u\cos u\,du=\log|\cos u|=\frac12\sin^2u+C$$

You can now go back to $\;x\;$ if you want

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\sec\theta\implies dx=\sec\theta \tan\theta d\theta$
$$\int{\frac{x^3}{x^2-1}dx}=\int{\frac{\sec^3\theta}{\sec^2\theta-1}}\sec\theta \tan\theta d\theta$$
$$=\int \frac{\sec^4\theta d\theta}{\tan\theta}$$
$$=\int \frac{(1+\tan^2\theta)\sec^2\theta d\theta}{\tan\theta}$$

$$=\int \left(\frac{1}{\tan\theta}+\tan\theta\right)d(\tan \theta)$$
$$=\ln|\tan\theta|+\frac{\tan^2\theta}{2}+C$$
$$=\frac12\ln|x^2-1|+\frac{x^2}{2}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Of course you ask for a trigonometric answer. We can still see some old neat trick from "factoring"...:Observe that $\dfrac{x^3}{x^2-1} = \dfrac{x(x^2-1)+x}{x^2-1}= x+ \dfrac{x}{x^2-1}$,and the rest you should know what to do...

Comment: OP knows this by long division. He asked for trigonometric substitution?

Answer (score 0):

It dosen't make sense to use trig substitution:
$$I=\int{\frac{x^3}{x^2-1}dx}$$
$$2I=\int{\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}dx^2}$$
Substitute $x=\sin u$:
$$2I=\int{\frac{\sin^2 u}{\sin^2 u-1}d\sin ^2 u}$$
$$2I=\int{\frac{\sin^2 u-1+1}{\sin^2 u-1}d\sin ^2 u}$$
$$2I=\int d\sin^2 u+\int{\frac{1}{\sin^2 u-1}d\sin ^2 u}$$
$$2I=\sin^2 u+\ln |{\sin^2 u-1}|+C$$
$$
I=\dfrac 12 (x^2 +\ln |{ x^2-1}|)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\cosh t$. Then,

$$\int{\frac{x^3}{x^2-1}dx}=\int \frac{\cosh^3t}{\sinh t} dt
=\int (\sinh t + \frac1{\sinh t}) d(\sinh t)\\
= \frac12 \sinh^2 t + \ln|\sinh t|+C
$$